# Where to place go.mod file

Tags: go, module

I have a repository structure as follows :-

```
xyz/src
      1. abc
            - p
            - q
            - r
      2. def
            - t
            - u
            - v
      3. etc
            - o
            - m
            - n
```

I have created a .mod file in src and run go build ./...
Except for local packages everything is fine. So if abc/p is being used in def then it throws the following exception :- cannot find module providing package abc/p. The idea behind keeping the .mod file in src package was to make sure the path is being found from where the mod file is located. Can anyone suggest where should the mod file ideally should be? also i tried placing it one directory above in xyz but still same issue as well as i created one for each sub directory. I am bit confused on this. Will I have to create separate repository for abc and etc. But considering gopath which earlier used to work for the same I think module should also be able to do the same. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `abc/p` a directory or file?

Comment: @Gavin it’s a directory which has go files in it

Comment: You put tho go.mod file at the root of your module. Module boundaries and source code repositories do not need to overlap.

Comment: @Volker by root you meant to say in xyz right ?

Comment: @Volker if i place it at xyz which is the root then i have to change all the imports inside the go file for other packages like xyx/src/abc in go file inside def directory

Comment: This is all wrong. xyz/src looks like a GOPATH based layout and no of course not below xyz. Please come up with a understandable real-life fs-structure. Nobody can discuss abc and xyz. Again. You place go.mod at the root of what makes a module. if xyz is a module: Put it there if o is a module: Put it there.

Comment: @Volker considering that i will create a folder root inside src and put the abc,def, etc inside that and put the mod file in the root directory as abc,def and etc makes a single module.Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The most common and easiest approach is **a single go.mod file** in your repository, where that single go.mod file is **placed in the root of your repository**.

Russ Cox commented in [#26664](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26664#issuecomment-455232444):

> For all but power users, you probably want to adopt the usual convention that one repo = one module. It's important for long-term evolution of code storage options that a repo *can* contain multiple modules, but it's almost certainly not something you want to do by default.

The Modules wiki [says](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#gomod):

> For example, if you are creating a module for a repository
>   `github.com/my/repo` that will contain two packages with import paths
>   `github.com/my/repo/foo` and `github.com/my/repo/bar`, then the first
>   line in your `go.mod` file typically would declare your module path as
>   `module github.com/my/repo`, and the corresponding on-disk structure
>   could be:

```
repo/
├── go.mod      <<<<< Note go.mod is located in repo root
├── bar
│   └── bar.go
└── foo
    └── foo.go
```

In Go source code, packages are imported using the full path including
the module path. For example, if a module declared its identity in its
`go.mod` as `module github.com/my/repo`, a consumer could do:

```
import "example.com/my/repo/bar"
```

That imports package `bar` from the module `github.com/my/repo`.

Answer (score 2):

I have a single go.mod in the root of my go application. I am using the following structure inspired by [Kat Zien - How Do You Structure Your Go Apps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oL6JBUk6tj0)

At the minute one of my applications looks like this

```
.
├── bin
├── cmd
│   ├── cli
│   └── server
│       └── main.go
├── pkg
│   ├── http
│   │   └── rest
|   │ # app-specific directories excluded
│   └── storage
│       └── sqlite
```

All packages are imported via their full path, i.e. `import "github.com/myusername/myapp/pkg/http/rest"` otherwise it causes problems all over the place and **this was the one change I had to make going from `$GOPATH` to `go mod`.**

`go mod` then handles all the dependencies it discovers properly as far as I've discovered so far.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that at the top level, "go run cmd/server/main.go" bombs out when it can't find the source files under pkg/...