# GOLANG "get" doesn't work properly with specific branches (dev vs main). go clean --modcache causes error (OSX, GO version 1.17.5)

Tags: git, go, go-modules

**Update** (14.01.2022): The main issue with "go get github.com/path_toPackage@specific_branch" still persists, and simply delivers something random instead of latest version, but I found a workaround by using a specific commit IDs provided by git. It works all the time and delivers what it should. Workaround : "go get github/path_toPackage@commit_ID". I did experiment with putting my main.go somewhere else (no effect on the issue), however haven't performed any changes onto go.mod file --> here I assume, it won't change anything, since main.go and the package itself are kinda independent elements.

**Update** (14.01.2022): It seems to be some caching or toolchain issue. I have updated the main branch, "go get" worked once and after it brings always the same version ignoring the changes on that branch. The "dev" branch stuck at some specific revision as well. In addition, I will experiment with putting the main.go in other repos or running it completely locally, as it has nothing to do with the module itself, the main.go only takes some functions and constants from that module.

**Original Issue:**

I ran into some weird issue while getting the specific github branch for my go project.

The main problem occurs when I am trying to "go get" the main branch of the repo. Weirdly everything works absolutely fine with *dev-branch*, the modules are being imported properly and I get the desired result (some console output). Commits work perfectly on the dev branch as well.

Here are the get commands, which I use:

*go get github.com/JimbiniBambini/go_test_packages/packages@dev*

*go get github.com/JimbiniBambini/go_test_packages/packages@main*

Importing the main branch runs into an issue, that the some variables/functions are not defined. At the same time, with "dev" branch everything works as expected. Cleaning the modules cache doesn't deliver any result :(

After hours spent with my larger repository I created a small test repo with following structure:

```
               go_test_packages/
                                main.go
                                /packages 
                                         /bla/bla.go
                                         /bli/bli.go
                                         go.mod
```

My idea was to create a portable package with some functionality, which I can import for all my further projects and basically develop it as an independent library.

So the main.go is an independent module, which uses the structs and methods from packages module.

E.g.

```
import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/JimbiniBambini/go_test_packages/packages/bla"
    "github.com/JimbiniBambini/go_test_packages/packages/bli"
)

func main() {
    var a bli.Bli
    a.TestVar = "smth"
    fmt.Println(bla.Env)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

The bli and bla packages deliver some constants, structs and functions:

***bli.go***

```
package bli

type Bli struct {
    TestVar string
}
```

***bla.go***

```
package bla

const Env = "main"

type Bla struct {
    TestVar string
}
```

As mentioned above, with dev branch I see a desired output. Importing the module from main branch delivers following error:

*# command-line-arguments
./main.go:13:14: undefined: bla.Env*

Difference between main/dev is only the value of *bla.Env* variable.

And lastly here is the ***go.mod*** file, which is placed in the "packages" folder:

```
module github.com/JimbiniBambini/go_test_packages/packages

go 1.17
```

I would really appreciate any help, since I am absolutely lost with this issue. My setup is OSX(version Big Sur 11.4) and GO 1.17.5. Previously I had an issue with installing of GO via dmg --> only upgrading via brew has worked and the newer GO-version was finally installed. Maybe this can help somehow.

Comment: Start by reading [Where to place go.mod file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52840620/1256452). Your setup (putting a `go.mod` file in a subdirectory of your project) is meant for "power users" and thus introduces all kinds of complexity. I have not experimented with this myself yet.

Comment: Ofc I can downgrade to a simplier solution, but the fact that something in the toolchain (GO, osx, git, my hands, etc) seem not to work properly brings me completely down. Yesterday I took a loooong break from this fight, and today it continues again :) Even in case, if the reason was ME, I'll let you all know here

Comment: you should put go mod at the top level. The things underneath are packages. If main.go is completely seperate, then its maybe better to make them siblings instead of parent child.

Comment: @TheFool I am experimenting now with various combinations, where I do put the main in dif. locations, commiting various things to the branches, so that I can destinguish what is what. For now I can say, it is some tooling issue. Maybe the commit summary, maybe something else causing this issue. 

My current state: I did nothing essential to the package, but the error with "go get" is gone. Now I simply see the previous version of my branch despite it has 10 new commits . So "go get repo@branch_name" seems to deliver something different than latest version on git, even if you do the modcache.